# WARNING: NEOS is temporarily unavailable. - Pyomo

Tags: pyomo, neos-server

I'm trying to learn how to send an optimization problem to NEOS Server to solve it with BARON, but I'm receiving an error which says NEOS is currently unavailable even though I've been trying it for some time. I've seen that there exists another question with the same error code, but it has not been resolved and people suspect it to be caused by using a proxy (Which I do not) therefore I opened another question.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = ConcreteModel()

model.x = Var(initialize=1.5)

model.y = Var(initialize=1.5)

def rosenbrock(model):

return (1.0-model.x)**2 + 100.0*(model.y - model.x**2)**2

model.obj = Objective(rule=rosenbrock, sense=minimize)

solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory('neos')
results = solver_manager.solve(model, opt='baron')

results.write()
```

And the output is:

```
WARNING: NEOS is temporarily unavailable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dorukeski/untitled/sa.py", line 15, in <module>
results = solver_manager.solve(model, opt='baron')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/async_solver.py", line 28, in solve
return self.execute(*args, **kwds)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/manager.py", line 119, in execute
ah = self.queue(*args, **kwds)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/manager.py", line 134, in queue
return self._perform_queue(ah, *args, **kwds)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/pyomo/neos/plugins/kestrel_plugin.py", line 128, in _perform_queue
raise ActionManagerError(
pyomo.opt.parallel.manager.ActionManagerError: Solver 'baron' is not recognized by NEOS. 
Solver names recognized:
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this post is an old post.
I see someone suggested the fix in this link, https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/2162

solution 1:
pip install --upgrade certifi

solution 2 if solution 1 not working:

1 - Open Internet Explorer as an Administrator (i.e., right-click on Internet Explorer and choose "Run as administrator")

2 - Navigate to https://neos-server.org

3 - Click on the lock icon

[Click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMayX.png)

4 - Click "View Certificate"

5 - Click "Install certificate..."

6 - Choose user or local machine, whatever is appropriate

7 - Select "Place all certificates in the following store" and choose "Trusted Root

8 - Certification Authorities"